# safe user input (of any kind) in another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have some troubles with a small programm.

There should be inputs by the user (of different type). But when the user puts in a ZERO ("0") the loop should stop and the programm should print all inputs before zero.

If the do-while loop has finished I'd like to go through the array and print all inputs
So i tried to safe all inputs into another array. Unfortunately my problem is, that i cannot safe the input (scanf) into another array. I hope you can help me.

Here is the code:

```
int *iarray(unsigned int n) {
    char input[MAX];
    char key[] = "0";
    char arr[MAX]       //troublemaker
    int i = 0;
    int *iptr = malloc(n * sizeof(*iptr)); // or iptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (iptr != NULL) {
        do {

            i++;
            printf("Geben sie Strings ein: ");
            scanf("%s", input);
            printf("%s\n", input); 

            /*
            arr[i] = *input;
            Here is the problem         
            */


            // i'd like to safe var input in another array for example arr[] and print it after the do- while loop          


        } while(strcmp(input, key) != 0); // compare if input = 0.  -> if input zero then break

    printf("Durchläufe %d\n", i);

    }
    return iptr;
}
```

Comment: So if you want to check for `0` then you should be checking for each character right? Something like getchar()? When you say inputs of different types is 10 a valid input since it has a 0?

Comment: you want `int` array as `iptr`, not `arr[]`.

Comment: `char arr[n*MAX];*arr = 0`, `strcat(arr, input);strcat(arr, " ");`

Comment: Unclear to me what the problem actually is: "the loop should stop" Does that mean it doesn't stop?? and /* here is the problem */ What problem??

Comment: Why no `;` in `char arr[MAX]`?  What else is missing in this post from the true code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution for my code, here we go. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion to improve my code. Cheers ;)

```
#define MAX 100


int *iarray(unsigned int n) {
    char input[MAX][MAX];
    char temp[MAX][MAX];
    char key[] = "0";

    int i = 0;
    int *iptr = malloc(n * sizeof(*iptr)); // or iptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (iptr != NULL) {
        do {                        
            i++;
            printf("Put in a strin: ");
            scanf("%s", input[i]);
            printf("%s\n", input[i]);           
            strcat(temp[i],input[i]);   // i use a temp array to safe all input stings there        
        } while(strcmp(input[i], key) != 0);    // compare if input = 0.  -> if input zero then break

    printf("Durchläufe %d\n", i);
    int l;
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {          //first loop creates amount of input strings
        printf("\n");   
        for (l = 0; temp[l] != NULL; l++) { // second loop prints every single letter
                if (temp[k][l] == 0) {  // if there is no if-statement i get a lot of crap from the output
                    break;      
                }else{
                    printf("%c" , temp[k][l]); // here i print my 2d arrays
                }
        }
        printf(" -> lenght %d", l);     

    }
    printf("\n");   
    }
    return iptr;
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

you could try sprintf(arr, "%s %s", arr, input).
At the end of the while you will have the arr[] with all the input